# Set cookies to redirect to the same clicked url next time

Tags: php, cookies, set

I have the following code

index.php:

```
    if(isset($_GET['lang']))
    $translate = new Translator($_GET['lang']);    
    else
    $translate = new Translator('en');
```

when the user make get request like this

```
index.php?lang=ru
```

i want the server to remember his request for the next time and redirect him from `index.php` to `index.php?lang=ru`

Comment: Cookie ? It is better to store it in session isn't it ?

Comment: but cookies last longer am i wrong ? sorry if my question is foolish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
 /*
 *  first get lang from url and set cookie
 */
 if (isset ( $_GET ['lang'] )) {  
    $lang = $_GET ['lang'];
    setcookie ( 'lang', "$lang", time () + 3600 );
} 

/*
 * second if lang is not set in url then read it from cookie
*/
else if (isset ( $_COOKIE ['lang'] )) {  
    header ( "location:redirect.php?lang=" . $_COOKIE ['lang'] );
}

/*
 * if cookie or url is not set then take default lang value 'en'
 */

else {
    $lang = 'en';

    header ( "location:redirect.php?lang=" . $lang );
}

?>
```

Comment: Mate i think your code have redirect loop so when the cookie already sent it will keep redirect you to the same place

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
   setcookie("lang", $_GET['lang'], time()+60*60*24*30);
   $lang=$_GET['lang'];
}
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) 
{ 
     $lang=$_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
      $lang="en";
}
    $translate = new Translator($lang);
```

Comment: when user go to `index.php?lang=ru` the site language change to russian so when user visit the `index.php` next time it redirect him to the russian language

Comment: thank you it worked but after set cookies i should refresh the web page to see the result any idea

Comment: There is no need to refresh. You can display page in preferred language first time